# How to write down SQL query to get the data count of a table?

Tags: sql

I have one table named FDR_DATA. There are following fields present in the table. Fields are: B1_NAME, B2_NAME, B3_NAME, ELEMENT, DATUM, WERT. Now I want to query the total number of data in this table and following output will generate.

`sql> select count (*) from fdr_data where datum like (select sysdate -1 from dual);`

(It only shows the number of counts)
But I want to print the datum (date) field beside the count.

`DATUM         COUNT`
`04.05.2016    899019`

How to write down the query to get the output like this way?

I have tried,
`sql> select DATUM, count (*) from fdr_data where datum like (select sysdate -1 from dual)`
But couldnot get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql> select count (*) as fdr_data from fdr_data where datum like (select sysdate -1 from dual);`

Output:

```
fdr_data    
-------- 
899019
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if any SQL dialects offer other ways, but as you haven't said what SQL server you use, but this should work:

`SELECT datum,count(*) FROM fdr_data WHERE datum LIKE (SELECT sysdate-1 FROM dual) GROUP BY datum;`

When the WHERE clause means there is only one row in the result it can feel strange having to add a GROUP BY clause, but the parser will not know so we add it to please that.